# $kP(x>k) \le E(XI(X>k))$

Tags: random-variables

Show that  $kP(x>k) \le E(XI(X>k))$ where X is Random Variable and k is arbitral positive number k

---

above is the question from my textbook but cannot recognize what the $I(X>k)$ denotes for.

Any hint?

Comment: I assume it is the indicator variable for the region.  That is it equals $1$ when $X>k$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: This looks similar to Markov's inequality.

Comment: @lulu thx.. then it's obvious..

Comment: Exactly.  Basically an exercise in the definitions.